# VideoWriter giving corrupted outputs

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, pyautogui

This is my code that records the screen. It was giving output with no problems and I did something that I don't remember, the program giving a 256kb corrupted ".avi" file.

```
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os.path
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from tray import systemTray


class Recording:
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        self.main_window = main_window
        self.startTimer = 0
        self.timer = QTimer(self.main_window)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTimer)
        self.out = None

    def trayInit(self):
        self.onLive = False
        systemTray(self.onLive)

    def createFolder(self):
        record_folder = os.path.expanduser("~\\Documents\\Records")
        print(record_folder)
        if not os.path.exists(record_folder):
            os.mkdir(record_folder)

    def recordLocation(self):
        self.record_folder = os.path.expanduser("~\\Documents\\Records")
        print(self.record_folder)
        path = os.path.join(self.record_folder)
        os.chdir(path)

    def initVideoWriter(self):
        prefRes = self.main_window.comboBox.currentText()
        self.width, self.height = map(int, prefRes.split('x'))
        self.prefName = self.main_window.lineEdit.text()

    def startRecording(self):
        self.startTimer = 0
        self.onLive = True

        self.main_window.pushButton.hide()
        self.main_window.pushButton_2.show()

        resolution = (self.width, self.height)
        codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
        filename = f"{self.prefName}" + '.avi'

        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, codec, 20.0, resolution)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        systemTray(self.onLive)
        while self.onLive:
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            frame = np.array(img)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            self.out.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow('Monitor', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('p'):
                self.onLive = 0
                self.stopRecording()
                break

    def stopRecording(self):
        self.startTimer = 0
        self.onLive = False

        self.main_window.label_2.setText("00:00:00")
        self.timer.stop()
        self.out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        self.main_window.pushButton.show()
        self.main_window.pushButton_2.hide()

        systemTray(self.onLive)

    def updateTimer(self):
        if self.onLive:
            self.startTimer += 1
            self.main_window.label_2.setText(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(self.startTimer)))

    def countdown(self):
        t = 5
        while t != -1:
            self.main_window.label_3.setText(str(t))
            QApplication.processEvents()
            time.sleep(1)
            t -= 1
        self.startRecording()
```

I tried changing the format, codec, fps, and file path. Did a debug and nothing happened. I Tried to add try-except blocks and nothing happened again. I changed the screenshot module with pillow, imageio-ffmpeg and it didn't work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you are getting the same result no matter how you change the code ... are you sure you are actually running the file you are modifying? Is the date of the output file changed to the time of running the script? Put a print statement into the run script to see and be sure you actually run the script you mean to run (sorry, I have not yet looked at your code, so I am commenting on "nothing happens" only).